# Transmit a string from one Pico to another Pico via i2c using Micropython

Tags: i2c, pi-pico

I want to transmit a string from one pico to another pico via I2C protocol , but I some how cant find a way to do it , my I2C scan function doesnt seem to detect another pico at all, is there a way to do it?
Code I've tried for now is

```
import machine


# Create I2C object
i2c = machine.I2C(0, scl=machine.Pin(5), sda=machine.Pin(4))
device = I2CDevice(i2c, 0x55)
# Print out any addresses found
devices = i2c.scan()

if devices:
    for d in devices:
        print(hex(d))
```

Comment: Ah, you need to first set one Pico as master, another or others as slave(s).

Comment: Yes but I cant find any method to set Pico as slave using MicroPython

Comment: why is that not your question?

Comment: I vaguely remember I gave that answer a couple of months ago.  You might also like to search rpi.org.forum for a similar answer.